# Despite using android-support-v7-appcompat library, Action bar is working wrong with android 2.2

Tags: java, android

I have used actionbarcompat in programming. Also I've added android-support-v7-appcompat library. Unfortunately action bar display as bellow (Items doesn't appear) :
[image]

please say right way.
this is my menu.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ActionBar2="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        ActionBar2:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Search"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_copy"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        ActionBar2:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Copy"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_share"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
       ActionBar2:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Share"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_share"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        ActionBar2:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Hossein"/>

</menu>
```

Comment: Show some code please? Have you added items for bar in code?

Comment: Honestly at this point I'd just drop 2.x support entirely. I'm not sure what your exact question is though - the ActionBar appears to be showing up, what are you trying to do with it? How are you trying to do it?

Comment: Nambari yes i aded, they show in android 4.0.3 but in 2.0.2 not.
i wrote menu.xml code blow.

Comment: powerj1984 my action bar items do not appear

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the answers in this question ([Android Studio - just can't get action bar / overflow to work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23720815/android-studio-just-cant-get-action-bar-overflow-to-work)).  If a hardware button is available no overflow menu will be shown.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me with appcompat v21:

On My onCreateoptionsMenu();

```
    final MenuItem switchButton = menu.findItem(R.id.action_import);
    final MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);

    MenuItemCompat.setShowAsAction(searchItem, MenuItemCompat.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
    MenuItemCompat.setShowAsAction(switchButton, MenuItemCompat.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
```